# What is the best way to do an API call to Shopify when multiple calls are needed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, shopify-app

I'm writing a backend using the MERN stack and need to do a GET request to Shopify's API to return some order information. I also need some information about the product, but this requires a GET request to another API endpoint. If I am returning the latest 100 open orders, then I would need to do 100 API calls to Shopify's Product API endpoint. This seems extremely costly and not a good solution. I feel like I'm missing a key element here. The code I have for returning order information is:

```
// Get the order information
const orderURI = encodeURI(`${URL}/admin/api/2021-07/orders.json?status=${p.order_status}`);
// Get the product information
const productURI = encodeURI(`${URL}/admin/api/2020-10/products.json`);


const headers = {
    'user-agent': 'node.js'
}

// Get order object
const shopifyOrderResponse = await axios.get(orderURI, {headers});
const retrievedOrders = shopifyOrderResponse.data.orders;

// Get product object
const shopifyProductResponse = await axios.get(productURI, {headers})
const retrievedProducts = shopifyProductResponse.data.products




let modifiedFiltered2 = retrievedOrders.map(order => ({
    "order_id": order.id,
    "source_id": order.name.substring(1),
    "order_data": order.line_items.map(variants => ({
            "product_id": variants.product_id,
            "sku": variants.sku,
            "title": variants.title,
            "variant_title": variants.variant_title,
            "variant_id": variants.variant_id
        })
    )
}))
return (res.json(modifiedFiltered2))
```

Ideally I want to include in the "order_data" object some information regarding the product, but that requires a specific API call. What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: use `GraphQL` API instead of `REST` API to get larger data in the single API call.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can get N orders in a single call to Shopify API, but you still need some more information of those N products & you don't want to call fetch product API N times.

I found this in Shopify Products API documentation
https://shopify.dev/api/admin/rest/reference/products/product#index-2021-07

This should work for you as it accepts a comma-separated list of ids.

```
GET /admin/api/2021-07/products.json?ids=632910392,921728736
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I can get N orders from one API call, but I need to do an additional N API calls to get more information that is specific to a single order. Thank you for the link. I will try to come up with a more workable solution than what is posted above.